# Elegir un valor duplicado de una columna con base en un criterio de otra columna en power pivot

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerpivot, powerquery

[image: Captura de pantalla]

Buenas tardes. Tengo el siguiente problema que no sé resolver:
Necesito agregar una columna con una leyenda que indique cuál instance number es el correcto. Aquí, por ejemplo, el correcto es el de arriba ya que tiene un valor de 1.998 en la columna Covered Line Number. Ya sé que es un valor duplicado porque ya tengo una columna que me dice cuántos duplicados tiene ese instance number. ¿Qué fórmula creen que pueda ayudarme?